# Uploading a picture - error

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, file, upload

I'm making a page in HTML that would pass an image to a PHP script, which then should upload the picture to a directory on the server.

This is my HTML form:

```
<form role="form" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 125px;">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="border-style: solid; border-width: medium; border-color: black; height: 206px; width: 156px; ">
      <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" style="margin-left:-15px" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <h3 class="text-center" style="margin-top: 0px">Choose your picture:</h3>
      <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" class="hidden" id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload"/>
      <label for="fileToUpload" class="btn btn-info col-sm-12" style="margin-top: 60px">Browse</label>
      <a class="btn btn-warning col-sm-5" style="margin-top: 15px" href="#">Skip</a>
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <button class="btn btn-success col-sm-5" style="margin-top: 15px" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is what it looks like:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/15xspjn.jpg

This is the PHP code from upload.php, I got it from w3schools:

```
 <?php
$target_dir = "../uploads/avatars/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
```

I'm getting "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file." while uploading a picture.

Any ideas why?

P.S. I've got "file_uploads = On " in my PHP configuration.

Comment: Sounds like the file might be too large.  What does your php error log file say?

Comment: If that was the case, I would also get "Sorry, your file is too large."...

Comment: basic debugging: did you check if you have the rights to move files into $target_dir? maybe you're trying to overwrite and that's not allowed. plus, your upload validation is incorrect. the FIRST thing you have to do with upload is check `['error']` to see if an upload occurred at all. until that's done, you have to assume that everything ELSE in $_FILES for that file is false/incorrect.

Comment: Your sample code is checking the file size of a successful upload to make sure it's not larger than 5mb.  However the if the php settings allows only a 2mb upload, I don't think it will upload your file, therefore when the code tries to move the file, it doesn't exist and you get "Sorry, your file was not uploaded."  By the way the default setting for upload_max_filesize is 2mb.

Comment: So I checked the error log and this is what I found:

Comment: [Sat Jul 25 09:18:16 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(../uploads/avatars/d462fd41-67c7-4262-922b-9455f0ac3fd9_zps3dry59z6.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/upload.php on line 38, referer: http://localhost/activateAccount.php
[Sat Jul 25 09:18:16 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpQ7AS82' to '../uploads/avatars/d462fd41-67c7-4262-922b-9455f0ac3fd9_zps3dry59z6.png' in /var/www/upload.php on line 38, referer: http://localhost/activateAccount.php

Answer (score 0):

As your `if statement` says :

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))
```

That will say whenever there occurs in the PHP function `move_uploaded_file` this will be called.
Information on how and when this error  occurs you will have to go to http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

For us ( the community of stack overflow ) its hard to detect why it is saying waht it is saying because it could be multiple problems and we are not sure what you did before this error occured.
Could you elaborate this?

What this function does in general is checking whether the POSTED file designation is a legit designation.
so you in case that would be `$target_file` which is this `$target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);` and the `$target_dir = "../uploads/avatars/"` this could have multiple problems like the directory is not accessible or it does not exist.
You need to make sure this directory exist.

The next problem could be that you are overwriting an existing file and this could not be done for some reason (using `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]` isn't really my ideal choice, i would do something like getting the time and date of today. That is if you dont need the file to be an specific name)

Let me know if any of this helped you :)

**EDIT** : You could also try to change `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file))` to `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir . 'test' . '.' . $imageFileType))` to test if that works.